# Extract a running ELF from a memory dump

Tags: linux, kali-linux, elf, forensics, dump

Our teacher gave us as homework a memory dump from a VBox (Ubuntu 16.04.9) and said that the message we need to get is printed by an ELF currently running in the VM.
This is my what I get after running `pslist` on the image.

```
Offset             Name                 Pid             PPid            Uid             Gid    DTB                Start Time
------------------ -------------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ------ ------------------ ----------
0xffff88007c998000 systemd              1               0               0               0      0x000000003552e000 -
0xffff88007c998e00 kthreadd             2               0               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c999c00 ksoftirqd/0          3               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99aa00 kworker/0:0          4               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99b800 kworker/0:0H         5               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99c600 kworker/u4:0         6               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99d400 rcu_sched            7               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99e200 rcu_bh               8               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c99f000 migration/0          9               2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f0000 watchdog/0           10              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f1c00 watchdog/1           11              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f2a00 migration/1          12              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f3800 ksoftirqd/1          13              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f4600 kworker/1:0          14              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f5400 kworker/1:0H         15              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f6200 kdevtmpfs            16              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007c9f7000 netns                17              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca90000 perf                 18              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca90e00 khungtaskd           19              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca91c00 writeback            20              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca92a00 ksmd                 21              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca93800 khugepaged           22              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca94600 crypto               23              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca95400 kintegrityd          24              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca96200 bioset               25              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007ca97000 kblockd              26              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb80000 ata_sff              27              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb80e00 md                   28              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb81c00 devfreq_wq           29              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb82a00 kworker/u4:1         30              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb83800 kworker/0:1          31              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb84600 kworker/1:1          32              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb86200 kswapd0              34              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb87000 vmstat               35              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec0000 fsnotify_mark        36              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec0e00 ecryptfs-kthrea      37              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f27000 kthrotld             53              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007cb85400 acpi_thermal_pm      54              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fc8000 bioset               55              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fc8e00 bioset               56              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fc9c00 bioset               57              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcaa00 bioset               58              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcb800 bioset               59              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcc600 bioset               60              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcd400 bioset               61              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fce200 bioset               62              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075fcf000 scsi_eh_0            63              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f26200 scsi_tmf_0           64              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f24600 scsi_eh_1            65              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f22a00 scsi_tmf_1           66              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f20e00 kworker/u4:2         67              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f25400 kworker/u4:3         68              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec6200 ipv6_addrconf        72              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035595400 deferwq              85              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035596200 charger_manager      86              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035593800 bioset               87              2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034c49c00 kworker/0:2          126             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff8800355e5400 kpsmoused            139             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034ee8e00 kworker/0:3          156             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec2a00 kworker/1:1H         166             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eef000 scsi_eh_2            167             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eee200 scsi_tmf_2           168             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eed400 bioset               169             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075f23800 raid5wq              241             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035590000 bioset               272             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035594600 kworker/0:1H         295             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035597000 jbd2/sda1-8          297             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880035590e00 ext4-rsv-conver      298             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034c4aa00 systemd-journal      354             1               0               0      0x0000000079614000 -
0xffff880035592a00 iscsi_eh             356             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880079103800 kworker/1:2          370             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034eeaa00 kauditd              372             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a478e00 ib_addr              382             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a479c00 ib_mcast             385             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47aa00 ib_nl_sa_wq          386             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47b800 ib_cm                387             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47c600 iw_cm_wq             389             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a47d400 rdma_cm              391             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880075ec4600 lvmetad              394             1               0               0      0x000000007c36c000 -
0xffff88007a478000 kworker/1:3          399             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880079100000 systemd-udevd        408             1               0               0      0x000000007c2c8000 -
0xffff880079100e00 iprt-VBoxWQueue      493             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff880034ebf000 ttm_swap             649             2               0               0      ------------------ -
0xffff88007a076200 atd                  730             1               0               0      0x000000007c3f8000 -
0xffff88007a070000 lxcfs                738             1               0               0      0x0000000079fe0000 -
0xffff88007b68b800 accounts-daemon      739             1               0               0      0x0000000079fe2000 -
0xffff880034eb8e00 rsyslogd             745             1               104             108    0x0000000079530000 -
0xffff880034c4e200 cron                 754             1               0               0      0x000000007a08c000 -
0xffff88007942c600 systemd-logind       758             1               0               0      0x000000007a6d6000 -
0xffff880079429c00 acpid                777             1               0               0      0x000000007917c000 -
0xffff880079428000 snapd                783             1               0               0      0x0000000079768000 -
0xffff880079428e00 dbus-daemon          785             1               107             111    0x0000000079470000 -
0xffff88007b17b800 dhclient             846             1               0               0      0x000000007a430000 -
0xffff88007942aa00 polkitd              898             1               0               0      0x0000000079b92000 -
0xffff880034ebd400 mdadm                907             1               0               0      0x000000007c3fc000 -
0xffff88007b17f000 VBoxService          941             1               0               0      0x000000007862e000 -
0xffff880034ebc600 named                1018            1               110             115    0x0000000079aa4000 -
0xffff88007a32c600 sshd                 1023            1               0               0      0x0000000034dbc000 -
0xffff88007b179c00 iscsid               1036            1               0               0      0x000000007afdc000 -
0xffff88007b178e00 iscsid               1037            1               0               0      0x0000000079bd0000 -
0xffff88007b68f000 irqbalance           1079            1               0               0      0x000000007a462000 -
0xffff88007b688000 login                1084            1               0               1000   0x0000000079dc0000 -
0xffff88007a074600 systemd              1157            1               1000            1000   0x0000000034c16000 -
0xffff88007a073800 (sd-pam)             1160            1157            1000            1000   0x0000000079a92000 -
0xffff88007a075400 bash                 1166            1084            1000            1000   0x0000000035720000 -
0xffff8800355e3800 ht0p                 1192            1166            1000            1000   0x000000007b982000 -
0xffff8800355e6200 htop                 1193            1166            1000            1000   0x000000007b9a2000 -
```

I have tried running `procdump` on a lot of processes there and then running `strings` on them but nothing seemed like the 'message'. I really have no idea what to do next, do I need to extract somehow the ELF that's running from memory? Also do you have any idea what process it might be or what else should I do?

Comment: Hint: are you not seeing any process with a funny name? It sticks out like a sore thumb...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am a begginer when it comes to process names. is it `(sd-pam)`?

Comment: Have a look at the last two ones. Still not seeing anything funny?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I dumped both processes and didn't see anything funny looking when using the `strings` command. `ht0p` was the first one that I saw actually

Comment: The teacher said it was printed by an elf, not that was easy to find with strings. I bet that either the binary is compressed or the string is hidden with simple tricks like stored it in an encrypted format or building it char-by-char. I would be my money on ht0p too.

Comment: So what do you think I should try? Currently i'm looking at the code through radare2 and there are like 200 functions beside main

Comment: Also, If I try to run the dumped process I get a segmentation fault

Comment: It seems procdump creates a core and not an executable. We cannot guess more than that. Why are you not doing your challenge?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have been trying to solve this problem for the last hour and all I've accomplished was to be sure that it's `ht0p` Using the bash command from volatility I saw that ./htop was ran last. Do you have any idea how I would go about extracting data from this process dump?

Comment: I used around 20+hours for my last reverse engeneering challenge. Cores are dealt with gdb or rr

Comment: ( core dumps) I mean

Comment: The first hint should be the name of your course. What are you studying? We cannot read your and your prof's minds and know what are course instructions. If you are in CS, it's one thing, but if you are in forensics, it will be totally different.

Comment: @ajeh It's forensics. I'd try to go with the process dump through radare but I'm a noob and don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but you should study better. The notion that a forensics student is asking for homework help on SE sounds ludicrous to me. You should be telling us.